# "Each PHP statement must be on a line by itself" Sonarqube pattern error

Tags: php

I'm analyzing a PHP code using Sonarqube, and I've noticed that in almost all files I have this error:

"Each PHP statement must be on a line by itself" 
(DisallowMultipleStatementsSameLine)

But when I check this files seems that there is no error.

For example, in this file the error is raised:

```
<?php
/**
 * Category of the question
 */
class Category {
    public $categoryId;
    public $name;
}
?>
```

How can be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try changing the line endings? Maybe `SonarQube` is expecting either *linux or windows line endings* and the file was saved with the opposite.

Comment: Yes. I've changed line endings to linux line endings, and then it worked. Thanks